# Jquery Fancybox 2 Buttons Helper Position

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I know that you can pass information to the fancybox function so customize certain settings, one of them being Top or Bottom for the buttons helper.  I also know that you can change the exact position of the buttons by altering the CSS file.  However, is there a way to have the buttons automatically adjust to the height of the picture, so that it is always right above the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving this for me with an additional little helper.

```
$('a.lightbox').fancybox({
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        title: {type: 'float'},
        buttons: {
            skipSingle: true
        },
        custom: {}
    }
});

$.fancybox.helpers.custom = {
    defaults: {
        position: 'top',
        space: 0
    },
    onUpdate: function(opts, obj) {
        this.setPosition(opts, obj);
    },
    afterShow: function(opts, obj) {
        this.setPosition(opts, obj);
    },
    setPosition: function(opts, obj) {
        // default position
        var top = '20';
        var offset = $('.fancybox-wrap').offset();
        if (opts.position === 'top') {
            top = (offset.top - ($('#fancybox-buttons').height() + opts.space));
        } else if (opts.position === 'bottom') {
            top = (offset.top + $('.fancybox-wrap').height() + opts.space);
        }
        $('#fancybox-buttons').css({top: top + 'px', position: 'absolute'});
    }
};
```

It is possible to set the position (top / bottom) of the controls and a space.

Cause I get in trouble with the position() function and css position 'fixed' on mobile devices, I'm using the offset() function and set the css position to 'absolute'

HTH

Claus

Answer (score 0):

you could edit this "top" in #fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico {top:50%;} or change it to {top:-20px;} or what ever you like in /js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css on line 153 which looks like this:

```
#fancybox-left-ico, #fancybox-right-ico {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    left: -9999px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;                   /* this line is what you want to change */
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 1102;
}
```

#### EDIT FOR OLDER FANCY

edits you can do in the following file: http://www.thomasantonini.webuda.com/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5

first at line 8: this will moce up the fancybox buttons with the player option

```
#fancybox-buttons.top {
    top: 0;
}
```

next change at line 146: this changes the click right (next) arrow

```
.fancybox-next span {
    background-position: 0 -72px;
    right: 0;
    top: -15px;
}
```

and at line 141: changes the prev arrow

```
.fancybox-prev span {
    background-position: 0 -36px;
    left: 10px;
    top: -15px;
}
```

with those arrows changes they are on the same height as the close button. Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: If I change these settings though, in the CSS file, then the buttons are permanently moved.  If a horizontal picture is loaded, and then a vertical picture is loaded right after, the buttons will remain in the same position.  This will either leave a gap between the horizontal picture and the buttons, or the buttons will be "over" the picture if the buttons are low.  I was wondering if there was a way the buttons can change height in response to the picture height.

Comment: @thomas have you got an example page or fiddle where this happens. if I change it to top:-20px; the button is always (responsive) -20px from top of the showed picture

Comment: I think I may be using a different version of the Fancybox plug-in. I am using v2.1.4 of fancybox.  I cannot find the #fancybox-left-ico or #fancybox-right-ico.  With the version I am using, I have to add a "helper" to the original plug-in, called "buttons."  It is this "buttons" menu, which shows forward, back, resize, or slideshow, that I am trying to move with the picture.  The "buttons" has its own css sheet as well, and there is a spot to adjust the height.  But the adjustment is permanent, not responsive.

Comment: If you go to http://www.thomasantonini.webuda.com/galleries/theeastcoast.html you can view the page with the fancybox, and if you look at vertical pictures and horizontal pictures, you can see the menu does not move.  The server of the site has been really slow today, so you may experience some delay when trying to view them.  Thank you!

Comment: The first line where you said to change #fancybox-buttons.top to 0, that moved the buttons with the player option right to the top of the screen.  That is the button that I am trying to make responsive to the picture, not the previous and next buttons.  No matter what size the picture is, even though the previous and next buttons are responsive, the buttons with the player option stays at the top of the screen.

Comment: I noticed at the top of the CSS file, the one that controls the helper buttons, #fancybox-buttons says position: fixed.  I wonder if this is what keeps the buttons always in the same position. Unfortunately, even if it is, I don't know what else would allow these buttons to move with the picture size.

Comment: well now I know which button you want to move. not sure if it is possible to change that with css only. will have a little time much later today to look and provide a real answer.

Comment: @thomas, are you still waiting for an answer? I had a look at it again. the buttons always are at top of the picture, could you fix it?